# Тестирование андроид приложений

Tags: юнит-тесты, android, java

Доброго времени суток! Возник следующи вопрос. Допустим, есть андроид приложение (на самом деле библиотека) и проект для тестов этого приложения. Проблема в том, что постоянно при запуске тестов получаю исключение NoClassDefFoundError. Например, в приложении используется класс HttpClient и при запуске тестов вываливается исключение NoClassDefFoundError: HttpClient. Я скачал и подключил android.jar, и вроде бы заработало. Но затем я получил уже исключение RuntimeException с сообщением Stub. Посмотрел в Интернете, там говорят, что вроде бы в android.jar есть только метаинформация о классах, но нет самих классов. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NoClassDefFoundError проверьте в манифесте есть ли класс.Скорее всего, вам надо подключить зависимости (dependencies), т.е. тестовое приложение не видит библиотеку.

Answer (score 0):

Советую начать использовать [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/).
Сам пользуюсь, весьма удобно.